# MVC JQuery Dialog submit more than 1 time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using JQuery's UI dialog to open a form. My attempt is to submit and close the dialog. I am having trouble.

The parent window opens the dialog (which contains a partial view) from click and form is submitted, for the first time, data is saved in DB. But if I click to open the dialog again and submit, there are 2 data rows saved in DB with the same value.

My code is below:

```
$('#newFileDialog').dialog('destroy');$('#newFileDialog').remove();
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

Your help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Partial view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("New", "File", new {}, FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "newFileForm" }  ))
{    
   @Html.ValidationSummary()    
   @Html.RenderHTML(
        new TabContainerViewModel(
                new TabViewModel { Name = "File", ViewName = "Common", Model = Model, Visible = true},
                new TabViewModel { Name = "Permission", ViewName = string.Empty, Visible = true}
            ) { Id = "createFileTabs", Visible = true })    
   @Html.SubmitButton("Send")
}
@{ Html.JQueryAjaxForm("newFileForm", "containerComponentContent", string.Empty, "$('#newFileDialog').dialog('destroy');$('#newFileDialog').remove();showMessagebox('New File added');"); }
```

Comment: Place breakpoint on your actionmethod to check what's causing double submission..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The reason was because of live event. So, after submission, I call die event, as follow:

`$('#form').die('click')`

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

After closing the modal, you have to reset the form (i.e `$form.reset()` )before using it again.

Comment: I tried $form.reset(), but I got an error from Firebug: reset is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your partial view code.

I think your form submitted 2 times. Check your generated request using firebug.

Comment: Yup, obviously, it's submitted 2 times the second time. I updated my post.

Comment: Are you created new dialog box each time on click??

Comment: Replace your line :  @{ Html.JQueryAjaxForm("newFileForm", "containerComponentContent", string.Empty, "$('#newFileDialog').dialog('destroy');$('#newFileDialog').html("");showMessagebox('New File added');"); }

Comment: Hi, yes, new dialog is created each time from click. I tried your suggestion, but it's still submitted 2 times the second time.